# JSF SelectOneMenu width

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I'm using selectOneMenu JSF 2 and trying to change the width of it is not working.

```
<h:selectOneMenu style="width:280px" styleClass="selectpicker"`>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="A" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="B" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="C " />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Only works when I remove the `styleClass = "selectpicker"`

Already add:

```
"data-width", "style="width:".
```

Any tips?

Comment: @thomas bormans, any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried to override the `ui-selectonemenu-label` and `ui-selectonemenu` css classes?

Comment: Hi Ouerghi Yassine, ui-selectonemenu-label and ui-selectonemenu, Is not it just for those who use PrimeFaces or RichFaces? Anyway, I'll check. Thank you!

Comment: Yes sorry, and your code works, what do you in the "selectpicker" css class?

Comment: Ok. Selectpicker is directly owned by the bootstrap.

Comment: Ok, did u try: `style="width:280px!important"`

Comment: Hi @OuerghiYassine  i used it important! and even then it was not!